# How to arrange divs inside of a CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css

So i have made a div inside of which are divs with h1 and some icons, but i'm not sure how to display them properly. I tried to use Grid, but i don't know if it's the right way.

The picture of my website:
[image]

The picture of a website i reference to:
[image]

So i want to arrange it like there, but i don't know any other way except of using Grid, with which i'm not very good.

Styles of grid:

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 75px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:40%;
    
  }
  .one {
    grid-column: 1 ;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  .two {
    grid-column: 2 ;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
  .three {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 3;
  }
  .four {
    grid-column: 4;
    grid-row: 4;
  }
```

Html code:

```
<div class="about">
    <img src="img/team.jpg">
    <h1>Voluptatem dignissimos provident quasi</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt<br> ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit</p>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="one">
            <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list"></i>
            <h2>Corporis voluptates sit</h2>
            <p>Consequuntur sunt aut quasi enim aliquam quae harum pariatur laboris nisi ut aliquip</p>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <i class="fas fa-cube"></i>
            <h2>Ullamco laboris nisi</h2>
            <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt</p>
        </div>
        <div class="three">
            <i class="far fa-images"></i>
                <h2>Labore consequatur</h2>
                <p>Aut suscipit aut cum nemo deleniti aut omnis. Doloribus ut maiores omnis facere</p>

        </div>
        <div class="four">
                
        </div>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with position: absolute?

Comment: i did it to position the grid on the right side of the page, but was it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made exactly shown in the picture you provided using `flex` and `grid`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
p {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

div,
h1,
h2,
img,
p,
svg {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr;
}

.container .split {
  display: flex;
}

.container .split img {
  max-width: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.container .split__right {
  padding: 2rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container .split__right header {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.container .split__right header h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container .split__right .content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.container .split__right .content .column {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.container .split__right .content .column svg {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  fill: #99b960;
}

.container .split__right .content .column .text {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.container .split__right .content .column .text h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.container .split__right .content .column .text p {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="split split__left">
    <img src="https://www.jobboardfinder.com/news/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/team.jpg" alt="Team">
  </div>
  <div class="split split__right">
    <header>
      <h1>Voluptatem dignissimos provident quasi</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta provident exercitationem quam dicta velit necessitatibus unde corrupti laboriosam quod ab culpa aperiam tenetur facere, ea quasi aut, saepe illo accusamus.</p>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="column">
        <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M19.875 3H4.125C2.953 3 2 3.897 2 5v14c0 1.103.953 2 2.125 2h15.75C21.047 21 22 20.103 22 19V5c0-1.103-.953-2-2.125-2zm0 16H4.125c-.057 0-.096-.016-.113-.016-.007 0-.011.002-.012.008L3.988 5.046c.007-.01.052-.046.137-.046h15.75c.079.001.122.028.125.008l.012 13.946c-.007.01-.052.046-.137.046z"></path>
                    <path d="M6 7h6v6H6zm7 8H6v2h12v-2h-4zm1-4h4v2h-4zm0-4h4v2h-4z"></path>
                </svg>
        <div class="text">
          <h2>Corporis voluptates sit</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis libero modi repellat, est qui accusantium neque officia voluptatibus facere quaerat fugiat! Inventore iste excepturi odit, itaque mollitia dolore accusamus voluptatibus.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M17.895 3.553A1.001 1.001 0 0 0 17 3H7c-.379 0-.725.214-.895.553l-4 8a1 1 0 0 0 0 .895l4 8c.17.338.516.552.895.552h10c.379 0 .725-.214.895-.553l4-8a1 1 0 0 0 0-.895l-4-7.999zM19.382 11h-7.764l-3-6h7.764l3 6zM4.118 12 7 6.236 9.882 12 7 17.764 4.118 12zm12.264 7H8.618l3-6h7.764l-3 6z"></path>
                </svg>
        <div class="text">
          <h2>Ullamco laboris nisi</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum illo, id omnis non ipsum perspiciatis fugiat labore repudiandae voluptate! Ducimus itaque enim, molestiae architecto ab aut doloribus minima debitis laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M11.024 11.536 10 10l-2 3h9l-3.5-5z"></path>
                    <circle cx="9.503" cy="7.497" r="1.503"></circle>
                    <path d="M19 2H6c-1.206 0-3 .799-3 3v14c0 2.201 1.794 3 3 3h15v-2H6.012C5.55 19.988 5 19.806 5 19s.55-.988 1.012-1H21V4c0-1.103-.897-2-2-2zm0 14H5V5c0-.806.55-.988 1-1h13v12z"></path>
                </svg>
        <div class="text">
          <h2>Labore consequatur</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos ratione sit veritatis! Aspernatur corporis non impedit, beatae ea eveniet alias amet veniam ducimus. Pariatur id temporibus facere perferendis sit qui?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M20.995 6.903a.997.997 0 0 0-.547-.797l-7.973-4a.997.997 0 0 0-.895-.002l-8.027 4c-.297.15-.502.437-.544.767-.013.097-1.145 9.741 8.541 15.008a.995.995 0 0 0 .969-.009c9.307-5.259 8.514-14.573 8.476-14.967zm-8.977 12.944c-6.86-4.01-7.14-10.352-7.063-12.205l7.071-3.523 6.998 3.511c.005 1.87-.481 8.243-7.006 12.217z"></path>
                </svg>
        <div class="text">
          <h2>Beatae veritatis</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque reprehenderit error ipsam commodi necessitatibus. Ipsam quae eius minima blanditiis nesciunt similique, cupiditate facilis. Quasi, maiores consectetur! Amet ut consectetur dicta.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[NOTE]** copy paste this code and view in bigger viewport because the result shown here is quite small. Remember it is not responsive.

Answer (score 1):

```css
            .wrapper {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
                grid-auto-rows: 75px;
                grid-gap: 20px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                top: 40%;
                grid-template-areas:
                    'item1 item2'
                    'item3 item4';
            }

            .one {
                grid-area: item1;
            }

            .two {
                grid-area: item2;
            }

            .three {
                grid-area: item3;
            }

            .four {
                grid-area: item4;
            }
```

```html
<div class="about">
    <img src="img/team.jpg">
    <h1>Voluptatem dignissimos provident quasi</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt<br> ut labore et dolore
        magna aliqua. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit</p>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="one">
            <i class="fas fa-clipboard-list"></i>
            <h2>Corporis voluptates sit</h2>
            <p>Consequuntur sunt aut quasi enim aliquam quae harum pariatur laboris nisi ut aliquip</p>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <i class="fas fa-cube"></i>
            <h2>Ullamco laboris nisi</h2>
            <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt</p>
        </div>
        <div class="three">
            <i class="far fa-images"></i>
            <h2>Labore consequatur</h2>
            <p>Aut suscipit aut cum nemo deleniti aut omnis. Doloribus ut maiores omnis facere</p>
        </div>
        <div class="four">
            <i class="far fa-images"></i>
            <h2>Labore consequatur</h2>
            <p>Aut suscipit aut cum nemo deleniti aut omnis. Doloribus ut maiores omnis facere</p>
        </div>
```